# An elegant way to flatten an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce, higher-order-functions

I am facing trival problem to flatten simple object with nested one inside.

Tried sollution fro SO, but it throws error:

```
const newWeather = Object.assign({}, ...function _flatten(o) { return [].concat(...Object.keys(o).map(k => typeof o[k] === 'object' ? _flatten(o[k]) : ({[k]: o[k]})))}({id: 1}))

// also tried these ones:

    console.log(Object.keys(weatherDetails).reduce((a, b, c) => {
        return Object.assign(a, {
            a: b
        })
    }, {})); 

// another one

let newWeather = Object.assign({}, (function() {
        var obj = {}
        for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(weatherDetails).length; i++) {
            console.log(i, Object.keys(weatherDetails))
            obj[Object.keys(weatherDetails)] = weatherDetails[Object.keys(weatherDetails)]
        }
        return obj
    })())
```

Here is my object I need to flatten, so we need to turn this:

```
{ 
    temperature: null, 
    humidity: null, 
    pressure: null, 
    windspeed: null, 
    pollution: {
        PM1: 1,
        PM10: 2,
        PM25: 3
    }
}
```

Into this:

```
{ 
    temperature: null, 
    humidity: null, 
    pressure: null, 
    windspeed: null, 
    PM1: 1,
    PM10: 2,
    PM25: 3
}
```

Comment: in lodash there is a simple approach. may be you can try that.

Comment: Could you also include the error details and possibly which line the error is happening on?

Comment: @jlafay there is no error, the results are just not what I expect so I am doing something wrong. 

Oh you mean the SO one, React says:

TypeError: can't convert null to object

Comment: Could you please link the answers you got your snippets from and add the errors you are getting?

Comment: `Object.assign({}, weather, { pollution: undefined }, weather.pollution)`

Comment: Should arrays be flattened too?

Comment: @briosheje don't expect arrays up there so it doesn't matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just merge and delete every child property that's an instanceof Object.

```js
let obj =
{ 
    temperature: null, 
    humidity: null, 
    pressure: null, 
    windspeed: null, 
    pollution: {
        PM1: 1,
        PM10: 2,
        PM25: 3,
  pollution: 4
    }
};

function flatten(obj)
{
 obj = Object.assign({}, obj);
 
 for (let i in obj)
  if (obj[i] instanceof Object)
  {
   obj = Object.assign(obj, obj[i]);

   // Prevent deletion of property i/"pollution", if it was not replaced by one of the child object's properties
   if (obj[i] === obj[i][i])
    delete obj[i];
  }
 
 return obj;
}

let obj_flattened = flatten(obj);
console.log(obj_flattened);
```

Comment: @JonasWilms about arrays, that's the first thing I thought as well, but OP in comments just said that they don't appear in the example, so the problem should not be addressed, apparently :|

Comment: @briosheje Correct.
Arrays will work in this case anyway, as it uses array indexes for keys

Comment: @briosheje Fur sure it should be addressed. If the solution aims to be generic, it should work in all cases.

Comment: @JonasWilms I do agree with you and I personally would address the issue, but still.. :)...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to have a generic solution, not one that's custom-tailored to your `pollution` example with static keys, here's a quick way of achieving that:

You just iterate through your object's property keys. If a property is an object (let's call it child object), you'll copy your child object's properties to your main object.

```js
const obj = {
    temperature: null,
    humidity: null,
    pressure: null,
    windspeed: null,
    pollution: {
        PM1: 1,
        PM10: 2,
        PM25: 3
    }
};

function flatten(object) {
    for (const key in object) {
        if (!object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            continue;
        }

        if (typeof object[key] === 'object' && !Array.isArray(object[key]) && object[key] != null) {
            const childObject = object[key];
            delete object[key];
            object = {...object, ...childObject};
        }
    }
    return object;
}

console.log(flatten(obj));
```

Comment: This code is incorrect, it deletes the entry after assigning the value entries. This results in missing properties if the entry key is the same as one of the value entry keys!!

Answer (score 1):

This would be easier with the Object.entries() method

You loop over the object keys and values, delete all entries that have an object as value and assign the entries off that value to the object.

```js
let a = { 
    temperature: null, 
    humidity: null, 
    pressure: null, 
    windspeed: null, 
    pollution: {
        PM1: 1,
        PM10: 2,
        PM25: 3
    }
}

Object.entries(a).map(([key, value]) => {
    if(value && typeof value === 'object') {
         delete a[key];  // Delete entry
         Object.assign(a, value); // Add values from entry to object
    }
});

console.log(a)
```

One liner:

```
Object.entries(a).map(([key, value]) => value && typeof value === 'object' && delete a[key] && Object.assign(a, value));
```

Also here's a immutable functional approach:

```
Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(a).map(([key, value]) => 
    value && typeof value === 'object' ? 
         Object.entries(value) : [[key, value]]
).flat());
```

Personally I prefer this last approach since it doesn't mutate the original or any object.

Comment: I'll have a look, typed this from my phone ^^°

Comment: Object destructuring must be wrapped in parens to distinguish it from a block.

Comment: Added one liner.

Comment: Added immutable functional approach and fixed object destructuring (should be array instead of object).

Comment: @mplungjan Made the snippet return and added null check.

Answer (score 1):

Just to share a different approach (elegant enough, maybe), here is a solution relying on function generators to recursively flatten an object.

Because it relies on function generators, you can eventually build the object dynamically and skip undesired keys due to the fact the the result is iterable.

The below example has intentionally been made slightly more complex to handle arrays and `null` values as well, though not required in the original question.

```js
const original = { 
    temperature: null, 
    humidity: null, 
    pressure: null, 
    windspeed: null, 
    arrayKey: [1,2,3,'star!'],
    fnKey: function(i) {
      return i * 3;
    },
    pollution: {
        PM1: 1,
        PM10: 2,
        PM25: 3
    }
};
// Flattens an object.
function* flattenObject(obj, flattenArray = false) {
  // Loop each key -> value pair entry in the provided object.
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    // If the target value is an object and it's not null (because typeof null is 'object'), procede.
    if (typeof(value) === 'object' && value !== null) {
      // if the targeted value is an array and arrays should be flattened, flatten the array.
      if (Array.isArray(value) && flattenArray) yield* flattenObject(value);
      // Otherwise, if the value is not an array, flatten it (it must be an object-like or object type).
      else if (!Array.isArray(value)) yield* flattenObject(value);
      // otherwise, just yield the key->value pair.
      else yield [key, value];
    }
    // otherwise, the value must be something which is not an object, hence, just yield it.
    else yield [key, value];
  }
}

// usage: assign to a new object all the flattened properties, using the spread operator (...) to assign the values progressively.
const res = Object.fromEntries(flattenObject(original));
console.log(res);
// sample usage by flattening arrays as well.
const res_flattened_arrays = Object.fromEntries(flattenObject(original, true));
console.log(res_flattened_arrays);
// custom object building by skipping a desired key
const resWithoutTemperature = {};
for (const [key, value] of flattenObject(original)) {
  if (key !== 'temperature') resWithoutTemperature[key] = value;
}
console.log(resWithoutTemperature);
```

Comment: @JonasWilms Thanks, edited above. That's clever, indeed, I didn't think about `fromEntries`, it makes it significantly cleaner, indeed!

Answer (score 0):

I usually use Lodash for these kinds of transformations.
With it, it's very straightforward to do so.

Check out the following code sample:

```js
const data = { 
    temperature: null, 
    humidity: null, 
    pressure: null, 
    windspeed: null, 
    pollution: {
        PM1: 1,
        PM10: 2,
        PM25: 3
    }
};

let flat = _.merge(data, data.pollution);
delete flat.pollution;
console.log(flat); // returns {"temperature":null,"humidity":null,"pressure":null,"windspeed":null,"PM1":1,"PM10":2,"PM25":3}
```

Comment: I'd think twice about adding a library with tons of other code and 4kb to your application for one very basic method.

Comment: It's a matter of preference. Lodash is still a very capable solution, but maybe a bit of overkill in small apps

Comment: This code requires the user to know about the exact properties that are an object, also adding lodash is as mentioned before unnecessary: ```_.merge``` can be literally replaced with ```Object.assign```.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (it will flatten any object contained in any object) iterating through the object attributes and identifying if an attribute is another object to flat and add to the "root" one:

```
var o = { 
    temperature: null, 
    humidity: null, 
    pressure: null, 
    windspeed: null, 
    pollution: {
        PM1: 1,
        PM10: 2,
        PM25: 3,
        newobject:{
            a:1,
            b:2,
            c: {
                x:3,
                y:4,
                z:5                 
            }
        }
    }
}

    function flatten(obj){
        let retObj = {};
        let objConst = {}.constructor;
        for (el in obj){
            if(obj[el] !== null && obj[el].constructor === objConst){
                retObj = Object.assign({}, retObj, flatten(obj[el]));
            } else {
                retObj[el] = obj[el];
            }
        }
        return retObj;
    }

    console.log(flatten(o));
```

Comment: No need for `objConst`, it contains a reference to `Object`

Comment: Add some explanation to your code please as mentioned in the StackOverflow guidelines.

Comment: objConst is the evaluation (after evaluate if the attribute of the object is not null) that the attribute is an json object, thats why i put it there.

Answer (score 0):

Post ES6, you can use the below as an elegant an clean solution:

```js
const data = { 
    temperature: null, 
    humidity: null, 
    pressure: null, 
    windspeed: null, 
    pollution: {
        PM1: 1,
        PM10: 2,
        PM25: 3
    }
};

const { pollution, ...rest} = data;
const flattenedData = {...rest, ...pollution};

console.log(flattenedData)
```